# routes file of laravel was changed to routes12. Now the other routes file not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two files named as `routes.php`. which is containing development environment routes for laravel and the other one `routes.php` is for real working links. I changed the name of first `routes.php` to `routes12.php` via phpstorm, so that i can work with real routes. Now the problem is that laravel is calling `routes12` every time i try to load the other real `routes.php` In the morning links were working fine even in the development environment. How can i solve this issue? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `php artisan route:clear` command from Laravel project directory.